# Testing VRFY command on a SMTP

Tags: python, file, sockets, smtp

I'm trying to test, giving a list of ip addresses and connecting to port 25, if `VRFY root` command exist.
this is the script I made:

```
import sys
import socket

socket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

with open('smtp_open.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print str.format(line)
        socket.connect((line, 25))
        banner=socket.recv(1024)
        print banner
        socket.send('VRFY' + ' root' + '\r\n')
        result=socket.recv(1024)
        print result
        socket.close()
```

and this is the output:

```
10.11.1.22

220 barry ESMTP Sendmail 8.11.6/8.11.6; Sat, 26 Oct 2019 10:56:33 +0200

250 2.1.5 root <root@barry>

10.11.1.72

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VRFY_script.py", line 15, in <module>
    socket.connect((line, 25))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 174, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

as you can see, it works for the first ip only, when it gives the second ip as input the output gives me the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the same socket for multiple connections. Instead you have to create a new TCP socket for each new connection. Reusing an existing socket will not work even if you've explicitly closed it.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I thought closing socket was enough.
By the way a new error is generated, I Included `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` into a `with` construct. and this is the ouput now:
`10.11.1.22

220 barry ESMTP Sendmail 8.11.6/8.11.6; Sat, 26 Oct 2019 11:22:57 +0200

250 2.1.5 root <root@barry>

10.11.1.72

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VRFY_script.py", line 14, in <module>
    socket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'socket'`

Comment: @DarkPassenger: This is different question and thus should not be asked in a comment.But in short: the package name you need is `socket`. Unfortunately you named your socket object also `socket` and thus you hide the package. Name your socket something like `sock` or `s` instead.